# Basic question but what is the best way to compare averages?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, descriptive-statistics, z-score

Fairly basic math question so apolgies.. say i have the following clusters, i calculate the avrage across all clusters so it's 363.33(100+450+540), would it then make sense to do the calculation 100-avg, 450-avg, 540-avg to see how above or below each segment is above average?

Just wondering what best way is to compare the spend. Is it not e.g. row 2 did 450-363.33 better than average, does such a statement make sense. Should i divide by standard deviation of the column and compare the z scores?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell what you are doing, so I will make an assumption that "CHASERS", "DEALERS", and "RICH" each stand for one unit.

Yes, it would make sense to say that "CHASERS" was \$263.33 below average and that the other two were above average. You also can calculate the z-score by dividing that value by the standard deviation of those three numbers, giving you a z-score of $-0.6983416$. With so few observations, I have difficulty interpreting this, but a z-score should give some idea of how far from the mainstream of the rest of the data a given point is.

Comment: CHASERS, DEALRES etc are the name of the segments, so for example the amount is the total amount people in that segment have spent who have been classed as that

Comment: What I wrote makes sense if you are interested in the three groups. If you are interested in the people who make up the groups, then the problem is harder, particularly if you don’t have more data (subject-level rather than group-level).

Comment: thanks i guess using the zscore would be ideal, but my complete number of groups is only 7, so would it not be unreliable

Comment: I’m not sure that the z-score helps you much. You have a clear interpretation that if a group spends $\$263.33$ less than average, the group spends $\$263.33$ less than average. What does it mean to be $0.6983416$ standard deviations below average? Sure, you can calculate that it means the group is $\$263.33$ below average, but you already know that.